# I'm confused with django project root and the virtualenv. Please guide

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm new to django and have a virtualenv outside my django project directory.

When I download open source django apps like python_social_auth using pip install, the apps reside in the virtualenv's site-packages directory and not in the project root. But I import them in my projects. Should I keep a copy of the downloaded apps in my projects root? Would that be necessary if I wanted to deploy the project?

Comment: You might find this chapter helpful: http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The libraries are not part of your code and shouldn't live in your project directory. They're dependencies, and should be installed by pip when you deploy just as in your development environment.

Comment: To add to this answer: make sure you use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and check in that file. So the next time you start the project you simply have to do `pip install -r requirements.txt` instead of installing everything by hand.